# How to make scroll in silverList?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am trying to make silver app bar,but stuck in a problem. I have used infitelist to build a list as i found infitelist handle the list view more niecly , due to which app bar won't go on top as shown in blow gif. As infite list is not supported i have wrapped it with container.
[image]
Below is the code

```
        SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                <Widget>[
                       Container(
                         height: 500,
                         child: Column(
                    children: [
                      TopListView(posts: state.posts),
                      Expanded(
                          child: InfiniteList(
                            loadingBuilder: (context) {
                              return const SizedBox(
                                height: 100,
                                child: LoadingIndicator(
                                  message: 'Fetching older posts',
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                            hasError: state.status.isFailure,
                            isLoading: state.status.isLoading,
                            itemCount: state.posts.length,
                            hasReachedMax: state.hasReachedMax,
                            onFetchData: () {
                              context.read<PostsBloc>().add(const PostsRequested());
                            },
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              final post = state.posts[index];
                              return PostCard(post: post);
                            },
                            errorBuilder: (context) {
                              return SizedBox(
                                height: 100,
                                child: Center(
                                  child: ReloadButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      context
                                          .read<PostsBloc>()
                                          .add(const PostsRequested());
                                    },
                                    message: 'Failed to fetch more posts',
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                            emptyBuilder: (context) {
                              return Center(
                                child: ReloadButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    context
                                        .read<PostsBloc>()
                                        .add(const PostsRequested());
                                  },
                                  message: 'No Posts Found',
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),

                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                       )
                ],
              ),
            )
```

How can we solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SingleChildScrollView` instead of `Container`.

Comment: No, it wont work as it says render box has size

Comment: SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                    <Widget>[
                           SingleChildScrollView(
                             child: Column(
                        children: [
                          TopListView(posts: state.posts),
                          Expanded(
                              child: InfiniteList(

Comment: This is the error 
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#e0c4b relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
SliverList
lib\…\posts\posts_page.dart:38
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by scheduler library ═════════════════════════════════
Null check operator used on a null value

Answer (score 0):

Actually, all you need is `CustomScrollView` and `SliverAppBar`.
here is a widget example:

```dart
Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: false,
            snap: true,
            floating: true,
            expandedHeight: 160.0,
            flexibleSpace: const FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: Text('SliverAppBar'),
              background: FlutterLogo(),
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  color: index.isOdd ? Colors.white : Colors.black12,
                  height: 100.0,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('$index', textScaleFactor: 5),
                  ),
                );
              },
              childCount: 20,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

[If you want to know more this is  SliverAppBar docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html)

Comment: I want to use infinite list instead of that, that's causing the issue

Comment: you can make your own infinite list that suits your own use case